# Scrolling an image within an image for a webpage

Tags: html, css

I am building a website for my app and would like to achieve something like this: http://letspip.com. An image centered in the screen with the content changing inside as the page scrolls. Been googling around and not sure how this is achieved. Can it be done in HTML5? Just want to know the name of the technique or something so I can get started. Any pointers would be really appreciated! thanks

Comment: What you see there is some `<img>` tags and a background image on the `<body>`. With the use of `postion:fixed;` elements, the combination of these give the effect you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at their source code.

HTML:

```
<div class="device"> <!-- The phone -->
<div class="mask"> <!-- The inner phone -->
<div class="service-bar"></div> <!-- Phone's navbar -->
<div class="screen skrollable skrollable-between" data-175p="transform:translate3d(0,0%,0)" data-150p="transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)" data-75p="transform:translate3d(0,-100%,0)" data-50p="transform:translate3d(0,-200%,0)" data-0="transform:translate3d(0,-200%,0)" style="transform: translate3d(0px, -100%, 0px);"> <!-- The part that changes -->
<section class="panel"></section><!-- Image 1 -->
<section class="panel"></section><!-- Image 2 -->
<section class="panel"></section><!-- Image 3 -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS from first section:

```
.device .panel:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url("http://o.aolcdn.com/os/aol/aol-alpha/pip-website/img/slide1.png");
}
.device .panel {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

So they have a div with the phone in it which is fixed at the center of the screen. While scrolling, the style element of the screen skrollable div changes from `transform: translate3d(0px, -200%, 0px);` (first image) to `transform: translate3d(0px, -100%, 0px);` (second img) and then to `transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px);` (third img). This changes each time a new part of the page is reached.

See the plugin [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) for further information on this or try to achieve it with your own javascript skills :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see this can be managed by fixed position and relative position. The image you are referring has been set as fixed. In given site [skroller](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) plugin is used to manage scrolling of different sections.